# How to do 2nd Where clause if first one yields no items?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a LINQ call:

```
return list.Where(item => condition1).IfNoResultsWhere(item => condition2).ToList();
```

How do 2nd conditional where only if the first haven't returned any values? I know I can split it and use if-statements but I would like to know if that is possible in one LINQ query.

Comment: This is not possible with standard LINQ and I don't see a problem in doing two separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own extension functions.

The following will take two conditions. If the first yields no results, the second is applied.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereFirstConditionHavingMatches<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate2
)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    if (predicate2 == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate2");

    bool found = false;
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element, index))
        {
            found = true;
            yield return element;
        }
    }

    if (found) yield break;

    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate2(element, index)) yield return element;
    }
}
```

One issue with the above is that the source is iterated twice, which might not be desirable. An improvement would be to save off the elements during the first pass, and then reuse those elements if needed on the second pass. Note that once we have a match, we can stop saving those elements.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereFirstConditionHavingMatches<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate2
)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    if (predicate2 == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate2");

    bool found = false;
    List<TSource> saved = new List<TSource>();

    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element, index))
        {
            found = true;
            yield return element;
        }
        if (!found) saved.Add(element);
    }

    if (found) yield break;

    foreach (TSource element in saved) {
        if (predicate2(element, index)) yield return element;
    }
}
```

The above could also be generalized to accomodate an arbitrary number of predicates by using a params array.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereFirstConditionHavingMatches<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate,
    params Func<TSource, bool>[] additionalPredicates
)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");

    bool found = false;
    List<TSource> saved = new List<TSource>();

    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element, index))
        {
            found = true;
            yield return element;
        }
        if (!found) saved.Add(element);
    }

    if (found) yield break;

    foreach (Func<TSource, bool> additionalPredicate in additionalPredicates)
    {
        if (additionalPredicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("additionalPredicates");
        foreach (TSource element in saved) {
            if (additionalPredicate(element, index))
            {
                found = true;
                yield return element;
            }
        }
        if (found) yield break;
    }
}
```

There may be room for additional optimizations, but it may serve your needs.

The above is not tested. If you discover any problems, please post a comment and I will make corrections.

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested in the comments you can't achieve what you are after with standard LINQ. By chaining calls you will always be operating on the return value of the first `Where` call rather than the original source list.

As such the best you can do is to split it as below, albeit you could achieve this with a one liner:

```
return list.Any(condition1) ? list.Where(condition1).ToList() : list.Where(condition2).ToList();
```